# split every single character in string. VBA.net

Tags: string, split, explode

can you help me on this?

I have a simple string:

```
str="Hello World";
```

I want to split it as that :

```
array= str.Split("",System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

result shoud be

```
array[0]="H"
array[1]="e"
array[2]="l"
array[3]="l"
array[4]="o"
array[5]="W"
array[6]="o"
...
```

But I don't know to "wildcard" the separator..

Any Idea on this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?

Just use [String.ToCharArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_ToCharArray):

```
SomeArray = str.ToCharArray()
```